# My Surface view flashes once and then disappears when I run it together with Camera view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-ndk, android-canvas

I am currently working on Eye tracking methods and as my application output, I need a graph which will track the movement of eye center. I have successfully finished the eye center localization part with the help of Fabian Timm's algorithm. But when I try to add the SurfaceView to my design, it flashes or a second and suddenly vanishes.
Below I have given my Javadoc and .xml file.

```
package org.opencv.samples.facedetect;

import org.opencv.android.BaseLoaderCallback;
import org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase;
import org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame;
import org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewListener2;
import org.opencv.android.LoaderCallbackInterface;
import org.opencv.android.OpenCVLoader;
import org.opencv.core.*;
import org.opencv.objdetect.CascadeClassifier;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;

public class EyeTrackingActivity extends Activity implements     CvCameraViewListener2,SurfaceHolder.Callback {

public native int[] findEyeCenter(long mFace, int[] mEye);


private static final Scalar     FACE_RECT_COLOR     = new Scalar(255, 255, 255, 255);
private Mat                     mRgba;
private Mat                     mGray;
private Mat                     mGrayNew;
private Mat                     mretVal;
private Mat                     scaledMatrix;
private Mat                     tempMatrix;
private Mat                     invertcolormatrix;

private File                    mCascadeFile;
private CascadeClassifier       face_cascade;
private CameraBridgeViewBase    mOpenCvCameraView;

private float                   mRelativeFaceSize   = 0.5f;
private int                     mAbsoluteFaceSize   = 0;

int leftEyePoint [] = new int[2];
int rightEyePoint [] = new int[2];

Point[] calibrationArray = new Point[4];

int screen_width, screen_height;
static double scale_factor;
Point leftPupil, rightPupil;

private static final String TAG = "OCVSample::NDK";

private BaseLoaderCallback mLoaderCallback = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
    @Override
    public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
        switch (status) {
            case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS:
            {
                System.loadLibrary("example");
                Log.i(TAG, "OpenCV loaded successfully");

                final InputStream is;
                FileOutputStream os;

                try {
                    is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.haarcascade_frontalface_alt);
                    File cascadeDir = getDir("cascade", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    mCascadeFile = new File(cascadeDir, "haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml");

                    os = new FileOutputStream(mCascadeFile);

                    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
                    int bytesRead;
                    while ((bytesRead = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                        os.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    }

                    is.close();
                    os.close();

                    face_cascade = new CascadeClassifier(mCascadeFile.getAbsolutePath());
                    if (face_cascade.empty()) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Failed to load cascade classifier");
                        face_cascade = null;
                    } else
                        Log.i(TAG, "Loaded cascade classifier from " + mCascadeFile.getAbsolutePath());

                    cascadeDir.delete();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "face cascade not found");
                }

                mOpenCvCameraView.enableView();
            } break;
            default:
            {
                super.onManagerConnected(status);
            } break;
        }
    }
};

public EyeTrackingActivity() {
  Log.i(TAG, "Instantiated new " + this.getClass());}


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.i(TAG, "called onCreate");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

    setContentView(R.layout.face_detect_surface_view);

    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    android.graphics.Point size = new android.graphics.Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    screen_width = size.x;
    screen_height = size.y;
    Log.i(TAG, "W: " + String.valueOf(screen_width) + " - H: " + String.valueOf(screen_height));

    mOpenCvCameraView = (CameraBridgeViewBase) findViewById(R.id.fd_activity_surface_view);


    mOpenCvCameraView.setVisibility(SurfaceView.VISIBLE);
    mOpenCvCameraView.setCameraIndex(CameraBridgeViewBase.CAMERA_ID_FRONT);
    mOpenCvCameraView.enableFpsMeter();
    mOpenCvCameraView.setCvCameraViewListener(this);


    SurfaceView surfaceView = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.surface_view);
    surfaceView.getHolder().addCallback(this);

}

@Override
public void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    if (mOpenCvCameraView != null)
        mOpenCvCameraView.disableView();
}

@Override
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_2_4_9, this, mLoaderCallback);
}

public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mOpenCvCameraView != null)
        mOpenCvCameraView.disableView();
}

public void onCameraViewStarted(int width, int height) {
    mRgba = new Mat();
    mGray = new Mat();
    mGrayNew = new Mat();
    scaledMatrix = new Mat();
    tempMatrix = new Mat();
    invertcolormatrix= new Mat();

}

public void onCameraViewStopped() {
    mGray.release();
    mGrayNew.release();
    scaledMatrix.release();
    tempMatrix.release();
    invertcolormatrix.release();
}

public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
    mGray = inputFrame.gray();


    MatOfPoint pointsMat = new MatOfPoint();

    if (mAbsoluteFaceSize == 0) {
        int height = mGray.rows();
        if (Math.round(height * mRelativeFaceSize) > 0) {
            mAbsoluteFaceSize = Math.round(height * mRelativeFaceSize);
        }
    }

    MatOfRect faces = new MatOfRect();

    if (face_cascade != null)
        face_cascade.detectMultiScale(mGray, faces, 1.1, 2, 2, // TODO: objdetect.CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE
                    new Size(mAbsoluteFaceSize, mAbsoluteFaceSize), new Size());

    Rect[] facesArray = faces.toArray();
    if (facesArray.length<1)
        return null;
    for (int i = 0; i < facesArray.length; i++){
        Core.rectangle(mGray, facesArray[i].tl(), facesArray[i].br(), FACE_RECT_COLOR, 3);

        /*scale_factor = screen_width/(double)facesArray[0].width;

        facesArray[0].height = (int) (screen_height/scale_factor);

        facesArray[0].y += 50;


        scaledMatrix = mGray.submat(facesArray[0]);

        Imgproc.resize(scaledMatrix, tempMatrix, new Size(screen_width,screen_height));
        Rect qwer = new Rect(0,0,tempMatrix.width(), tempMatrix.height());*/
        findEyes(mGray, facesArray[0]);

    }

    return mGray;

}

private Mat findEyes(Mat frame_gray, Rect face) {

    Mat faceROI = frame_gray.submat(face);

      int eye_region_width = (int) (face.width * 0.35);
      int eye_region_height = (int) (face.width * 0.30);
      int eye_region_top = (int) (face.height * 0.25);
      int leftEyeRegion_x = (int) (face.width * 0.13);
      Rect leftEyeRegion = new Rect(leftEyeRegion_x,eye_region_top,eye_region_width,eye_region_height);
      int [] leftEyeArray = {leftEyeRegion_x,eye_region_top,eye_region_width,eye_region_height};
      Rect rightEyeRegion = new Rect(face.width - eye_region_width - leftEyeRegion_x,
              eye_region_top,eye_region_width,eye_region_height);
      int [] rightEyeArray = {face.width - eye_region_width - leftEyeRegion_x,
              eye_region_top,eye_region_width,eye_region_height};


      // TODO: error when loading the native function
      leftEyePoint = findEyeCenter(faceROI.getNativeObjAddr(), leftEyeArray);
      rightEyePoint = findEyeCenter(faceROI.getNativeObjAddr(), rightEyeArray);
      leftPupil = new Point(leftEyePoint[0], leftEyePoint[1]);
      rightPupil = new Point(rightEyePoint[0], rightEyePoint[1]); 
      //-- Find Eye Centers

      rightPupil.x += Math.round(rightEyeRegion.x + face.x);
      rightPupil.y += Math.round(rightEyeRegion.y + face.y) ;
      leftPupil.x += Math.round(leftEyeRegion.x + face.x);
      leftPupil.y += Math.round(leftEyeRegion.y + face.y);

      //rightPupil = Math.round(rightPupil);
      //leftPupil = unscalePoint(leftPupil);


      // draw eye centers
        Core.circle(mGray, rightPupil, 3, FACE_RECT_COLOR);
        Core.circle(mGray, leftPupil, 3, FACE_RECT_COLOR);
        return mGray;



    }

private static Point unscalePoint(Point p) {

    int x = (int)(p.x);
    int y = (int) Math.round(p.y / scale_factor);

    return new Point(x, y - 50);
}


@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}


@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
        int height) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(3);
    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    Path path = new Path();
    path.moveTo(0, 0);
    path.lineTo(150, 150);

    Canvas canvas = holder.lockCanvas();
    canvas.drawRGB(255, 128, 128);
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
    holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);

}


@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```

And my .xml file is as below

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".EyeTrackingActivity" >

<org.opencv.android.JavaCameraView
    android:id="@+id/fd_activity_surface_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<SurfaceView
    android:id="@+id/surface_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dip" 
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
```

Comment: What's in your logcat log output?

Comment: The problem has been resolved but now I have a new task with the same code. I need to plot my x-y coordinates in real time with the help of canvas. Is it possible for you to help me out with this?

Comment: Comments are not for asking another question. Please read on [comments](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). If the problem was solved, please put an answer and accept that so people will see that no help is needed with this particular question.

Comment: in.xml file, I have changed the camera layout as below.     <org.opencv.android.JavaCameraView
        android:id="@+id/fd_activity_surface_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/surface_view" />  this will make the Surface view to come below the camera view and not get hidden by the same.

Comment: thanks, answer is a large box a bit below the text 'Your answer', please put the xml there, once you'll post it, there will be a tick symbol to the left which will allow you to accept it. Thanks for being a good citizen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer I found is in the .xml file. The modified .xml is as shown below

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="fill"
tools:context=".EyeTrackingActivity" >

<org.opencv.android.JavaCameraView
    android:id="@+id/fd_activity_surface_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/surface_view" />

<SurfaceView
    android:id="@+id/surface_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dip" 
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
```